# How to cache list using hibernate ehcache

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, ehcache

i am using hibernate ehcache in my web application.i cached the list like below.

```
model.put("projecttype",sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(TblProjectType.class).list());
         System.out.println("Fetch Count="+ stats.getEntityFetchCount());
        System.out.println("Second Level Hit Count="+ stats.getSecondLevelCacheHitCount());
        System.out.println("Second Level Miss Count="+ stats.getSecondLevelCacheMissCount());
        System.out.println("Second Level Put Count="+ stats.getSecondLevelCachePutCount());
```

**EHCACHE.xml**

```
<cache
    name="com.uniphore.timesheet.domain.TblProjectType"
    maxElementsInMemory="1000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300"
    timeToLiveSeconds="600"
    overflowToDisk="true" statistics="true"/>
TblProjectType table has 5 rows only.
```

My Output:

```
--First---
Fetch Count=0
Second Level Hit Count=0
Second Level Miss Count=0
Second Level Put Count=0
--Second---
Fetch Count=0
Second Level Hit Count=0
Second Level Miss Count=0
Second Level Put Count=11
---Third--
Fetch Count=0
Second Level Hit Count=0
Second Level Miss Count=0
Second Level Put Count=22
```

My Ebtity Class:

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="tblProjectType")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @Repository
    public class TblProjectType  implements java.io.Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1798070786993154681L;
         @Id
         @GeneratedValue
         @Column(name ="ID")
         private short id;
         @Column(name ="TypeName")
         private String typeName;
         @Column(name="CreatedDate")
         private Date createdDate;
         @Column(name="ModifiedDate")
         private Date modifiedDate;
         @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tblProjectType", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
         private Set<TblStage> tblStages = new HashSet<TblStage>(0);
         @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tblProjectType", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
         private Set<TblProject> tblProjects = new HashSet<TblProject>(0);

        //getters and setters 



    }
```

Each time put count increases 11.But no other values are changed.why second level cache not hits?

why query is executed every time instead of take the result from second level cache?

Why second level put count increase when  i hit the same query it should update instead of insert?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: @Madheshwhat is this `model` doing here, and how are you caching your entity and query

Comment: Tblproject type is my entity class.i store that query result in cache.by using ehcache.xml

Comment: Have you marked the TblProjectType entity as cacheable? Post your TbProjectType class code.

Comment: @Andy Durfens,i have marked tblprojecttype as entity class.i have posted my entity class in my question.

Comment: It's strange. I am assuming you have enabled second level and query cache both. Can you post the hibernate config too?

Answer (score 0):

Try two things.

1. Specify a cache region in the entity class

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name="tblProjectType")
   @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE, region="yourcacheregion")
   @Repository
   public class TblProjectType  implements java.io.Serializable {
   }
   ```
2. Mark the criteria query as cacheable

   model.put("projecttype",sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(TblProjectType.class)..setCacheable(true).list());

I am assuming you have the hibernate configuration as below

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>
<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
```

Comment: yes your assumption is correct.but i am gettig this error DummyPinnedKey cannot be cast to org.hibernate.cache.QueryKey.

Comment: I didn't follow you. What and when do you get an error?

Comment: sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(TblProjectType.class).setCacheable(true).list() when try to execute this this query i am getting the exception DummyPinnedKey cannot be cast to org.hibernate.cache.QueryKey

Comment: You don't get this exception when not setting cacheable true?